# Algolia Vue Instant Search – Toggling class is resetting attributes

Tags: vue.js, algolia, vue-instant-search

I have an Algolia [refinement list](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/refinement-list/vue/) but each time I toggle a class around it, the query disappears. I can't work out what it is that is resetting the values.

Here is my current example:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :class="{active}">
    <ais-instant-search :search-client="searchClient" index-name="products">
      <button @click="toggleActive">Toggle</button>
      <span>&larr; Pressing this is wiping the search.</span>
      <div class="dietary-requirements-dropdown--checkboxes">
        <ais-refinement-list attribute="dietary" :sort-by="['name:asc']"></ais-refinement-list>
      </div>
    </ais-instant-search>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch/lite";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      active: false,
      searchClient: algoliasearch(
        "ZVIJ67X9P8",
        "df6c2515326327131df74c0a879b8794"
      )
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleActive() {
      this.active = !this.active;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.dietary-requirements-dropdown--checkboxes {
  opacity: 1;
  .active & {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}
</style>
```

**Demo here:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-z5woy

Comment: I'm pretty sure Vue has to rerender the template since the variable is used inside the DOM, forcing the child component to update and the algolia component can't persist the selection.  You may be able to get away to using `v-once` on the `ais-instant-search` component.

Comment: @StevenB. thanks Steven, I struggled with it all yesterday and woke up this morning with a similar feeling before reading your answer. Replacing the reactive class with a watcher, and a `querySelector.classList.toggle` solved everything. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @StevenB., the issue is the re-rendering of the dom elements, due to the reactive class names.

Specifically, this attribute on the wrapper component:

```
:class="{active}"
```

Rerenders all contents including this `ais-refinement-list`. This is a problem, as when the list is destroyed, the reactive search effectively treats all the non-existent checkboxes as **not** checked, resetting the search.

It was a simple fix, while not perfectly reactive. I replaced:

```
toggleActive() {
  this.active = !this.active;
}
```

With a "vanilla":

```
toggleActive() {
  document.querySelector("#app").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

It would also be better to use `$refs` when available

```
toggleActive() {
  this.$refs.filters.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

This means the DOM isn't re-rendered, the checkboxes aren't reset, and the search remains the same.